# How to implement optimization of INNER JOINS (push down) for Mongo Storage Plugin in Apache Drill?

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, odbc, apache-drill

I would like to extend the [Apache Drill Mongo Storage Plugin](https://drill.apache.org/docs/mongodb-storage-plugin/) to push down INNER JOINs. Therefore I would like to rewrite `INNER JOIN` into the mongo aggregation pipeline.

How do we need to start to implement the rewrite in [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/).

Here is a SQL example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mymongo.db`.`test` `test`
  INNER JOIN `mymongo.db`.`test2` `test2`
  ON (`test`.`id` = `test2`.`fk`)
WHERE `test2`.`date` = '09.05.2017'
```

I have found the [push down](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-mongo/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/mongo/MongoPushDownFilterForScan.java) of `WHERE` clauses in the Mongo Storage Plugin. But I am still struggling to do the same for `INNER JOINS`. How would the constuctor of `public class MongoPushDownInnerJoinScan extends StoragePluginOptimizerRule` look like? Which equivalent of `MongoGroupScan` ([`AbstractGroupScan`](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-mongo/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/mongo/MongoGroupScan.java)) would I have to implement? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should try the drill mailing list instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an inner join with the aggregation framework similar to SQL you can do it with the pipeline stage $lookup.

```
$lookup:
    {
    from: <collection to join>,
    localField: <field from the input documents>,
    foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
    as: <output array field>
    }
}
```